# ios playing video from php in webview

Tags: php, ios, swift

hello i have a php script

```
<?php

$link='http://vod.adicis.cd/p/102/sp/10200/embedIframeJs/uiconf_id/23448125/partner_id/102?autoembed=true&entry_id=0_s1i9ck1l&playerId=kaltura_player_1504000771&cache_st=1504000771&width=500&height=433&flashvars[streamerType]=auto';

echo '<script src='.$link.'> </script>';"


?>
```

this script helps me to download a video in a plattform named kaltura and you can play it throught the player of the platform

now i am loading the page in the webview

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

      mywebview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;

    loadWebPart()

}

func loadWebPart()
{


    let url = NSURL (string: "http://media.adicis.cd/dov/mobile752017/webpart/safaritest.php")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    mywebview.loadRequest(request as URLRequest)



}
```

the problem is the video is load and you can see the thumbnail but when you click in the player it is not playing

i did the same logic in android webview it is worked,

Comment: add the delegate and check?

Comment: facing the same problem after adding

Comment: thanks for your reaction, the script is working perfectly , because if you try that script in browser it is working.

Comment: i would like to know  the importance of playsinline in the sever side

Comment: unfortunately i  am using the link, with Android webvview it is working peferctly.

Comment: you may check it with your mobile browser you may notice an other behavior, because the plattform from where i am taking video it is dedicated for mobile

Answer (score 0):

After making many researches my problem was in the background. i should open the 88 of my webserver nginx  so as to authorize the streaming in all browsers. below link interresting help from a wornderful guy jess portnoy

https://forum.kaltura.org/t/katura-player-kwidget-loads-video-correctely-but-not-playing-progressbar-is-loading-without-the-end/7661